# Explode txt file into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, text, multidimensional-array, explode

I have a .txt file that looks like the one below:

```
Test = 10849831 = August 6, 2013:
56cake = 0 = August 6, 2013:
Wwe = 812986192 = August 6, 2013:
```

I want to explode the file above to make an array that looks like the one below:

```
Array
(
[Test] => Array
  (
  [0] => 10849831
  [1] => August 6, 2013
  )
[56cake] => Array
  (
  [0] => 0
  [1] => August 6, 2013
  )
[Wwe] => Array
  (
  [0] => 812986192
  [1] => August 6, 2013
  )
)
```

How can I accomplish this? I've already tried using something like `explode(":", $data)` but I don't know how to use it to do what I want above. I'm fairly new with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
  // Sample text data
  $text = 'Test = 10849831 = August 6, 2013:
Test = 10849831 = August 6, 2013:
56cake = 0 = August 6, 2013:
Wwe = 812986192 = August 6, 2013:';

  $text = explode( PHP_EOL, $text ); // split by lines using linebreaks
  // $text = explode( ":", $text ); // you can also split by lines with ':'  
  $arr  = array(); // Our array which holding the output
  // print_r( $text );

  foreach( $text as $line ) { // loop through lines
    $line = array_map( "trim", explode( "=", $line ) ); // split by '=' sign and do 'trim'
    // print_r( $line );
    if ( count( $line ) === 3 ) {
      $key  = strtolower( $line[0] ); // make the key lowercase (case insensitive)
      $val1 = $line[1];
      // process the date and remove day from date
      $val2 = trim( $line[2], ":" ); // remove ':' from the end of date
      $val2 = array_map( "trim", explode( " ", $val2 ) ); // split by space sign and do a 'trim'
      $val2 = $val2[0]." ".$val2[2]; // join year and month parts

      if ( isset( $arr[$key] ) ) { // check if the key already exists
        // key exists,  push new values
        array_push( $arr[$key], $val1, $val2 );
        continue; // key exists so continue the loop
      }
      // key doesn't exists in array so add the values
      $arr[$key]  = array( $val1, $val2 );
    }
  }

  // there is an altwernate way to remove duplicate values using 'array_unique'
  // uncomment below code if you dont want duplicate values
  /*if ( !empty( $arr ) ) {
    $arr  = array_map( "array_unique", $arr ); // remove duplicate values from array using 'array_unique'
  }*/

  print_r( $arr );
?>
```

**Here is the list of functions which i used in my code and link to those functions documentation**

> 1. [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
> 2. [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
> 3. [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)
> 4. [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)
> 5. [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)
> 6. [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
> 7. [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)
> 8. [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: The code seems to be removing duplicates, why is this happening? In my actual txt file, I have more than one data value with the name "Test" or "56cake."

Comment: @user2680030 You didn't mentioned that, don't worry code updated, try now :)

Comment: Thank you SO much. One last thing, is there a way to remove the number from the date portion? So instead of it being `August 6, 2013` or `August 6 2013` could it just be `August 2013`?

Comment: Ugh, I'm so sorry for the questions. However could you make the code not case sensitive? Because in my real text file, it takes `test` and `Test` as two different things. Another example is that it takes `appleb_oy` and `Appleb_Oy` as two different things. However, I want them to be under the same data element.

Comment: Use `strtolower` to make a string lowercase and set it as the key, answer updated

Comment: I honestly can't thank you enough. This was an amazing answer, and you've fulfilled every single on of my requests!

Answer (score 2):

Just a little bit of array iteration does the trick with: [`explode`](http://php.net/explode), [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map), [`trim`](http://php.net/trim), [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) and `foreach`.

**PHP Example**

```
$txt = <<<DOC
Test = 10849831 = August 6, 2013:
56cake = 0 = August 6, 2013:
Wwe = 812986192 = August 6, 2013:
DOC;

$Output = array();
$Lines = explode(":", $txt);

foreach($Lines as $line) {
    $Rows = array_map('trim', explode(" = ", $line));
    if(!isset($Rows[0], $Rows[1], $Rows[2])) continue;
    $Output[$Rows[0]] = array($Rows[1], $Rows[2]);
}

print_r($Output);
```

**PHP Code Output**

```
Array
(
    [Test] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10849831
            [1] => August 6, 2013
        )

    [56cake] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => August 6, 2013
        )

    [Wwe] => Array
        (
            [0] => 812986192
            [1] => August 6, 2013
        )

)
```

**The Code Explained**

1. Break up the lines with `explode(":", $txt)`
2. Loop through each line and break up each section by `=` again using `explode`
3. Use `array_map` to cycle each value and remove whitespace
4. Check to ensure we have 3 values with `isset`, if not, then skip the iteration
5. Push our collected values into the output array

Comment: The code seems to be removing duplicates, why is this happening? In my actual txt file, I have more than one data value with the name "Test" or "56cake."

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-use this code:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$result = array();

$string = 'Test = 10849831 = August 6, 2013';
$temp1 = explode("=", $string, 2);
print_r($temp1);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Test 
    [1] =>  10849831 = August 6, 2013
)
*/
$key = $temp1[0];

$result[$key] = explode("=", $temp1[1]);

print_r($result);
/*
Array
(
    [Test ] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  10849831 
            [1] =>  August 6, 2013
        )

)
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$chunks = explode(':', $text);
$out = array();
foreach ($chunks as $key => $value){
    $parts = explode('=', $value);
    if (count($parts) == 3){
        $out[trim($parts[0])] = array(trim($parts[1]), trim($parts[2]));
    }
}
print_r($out);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have use explode like this:

```
<?php
//
//Test = 10849831 = August 6, 2013:
//56cake = 0 = August 6, 2013:
//Wwe = 812986192 = August 6, 2013:

function read_data_file( $file ) {
    $file_open = fopen( $file , 'r' );
    $file_data = fread( $file_open , filesize( $file ) );
    fclose( $file_open );

    return $file_data;
}

$result_read = read_data_file('/home/josecarlos/Desktop/test.txt');

$result_explode = explode("\n", $result_read );

$final_result = array();

foreach ($result_explode as $key => $cursor){
    $explode = explode("=",  $cursor );
    if (isset($explode[0]) && $explode[0] != ''){
        $final_result[trim($explode[0])]  =array (trim($explode[1]),trim($explode[2])) ;
    }
}

var_dump($final_result);
```

The result is:

```
array(3) {
  'Test' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "10849831"
    [1] =>
    string(15) "August 6, 2013:"
  }
  '56cake' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "0"
    [1] =>
    string(15) "August 6, 2013:"
  }
  'Wwe' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(9) "812986192"
    [1] =>
    string(15) "August 6, 2013:"
  }
}
```